# How to make flask response to client asynchronously?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Flask is a single thread web server. But I want to make it won't block when handle some time consuming request.

For example:

```
from flask import Flask
import time
import sys
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    print "request"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    for _ in range(10000000):
        for j in range(10000000):
            i = 1
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want when every client request to server, it always output "request" on console immediately. I have try `gunicorn` and run with `gunicorn -k gevent -w 4 a:app` but it still appears synchronous.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430692/perform-task-directly-after-returning-json/18430861#18430861

Comment: http://python-rq.org/

Comment: _"Flask is a single thread web server."_ This is not correct. Flask is a framework, and has a function to help give you create a debug server. That [debug server can use multiple threads or processes](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.run). _"I want when every client request to server, it always output "request" on console immediately.... but it still appears synchronous"_ What is the exact output you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

[This snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/73/) is a good starting point.

You also should look into [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [RQ](http://python-rq.org/), they're the right thing to use for larger projects, more importantly they're not Flask-specific.

They also have Flask integration each, [Flask-Celery](https://github.com/ask/flask-celery/) and [Flask-RQ](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-rq).

Comment: From Flask-Celery page: «FROM CELERY 3.0 THIS LIBRARY IS NO LONGER NECESSARY, INSTEAD YOU SHOULD USE THE STANDARD CELERY API». Also you can check [this post](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) for details with Flask and Celery.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking about something called "streaming". For Flask this can be accomplished using generator functions and the `yield` keyword.

Streaming is covered in more detail in the official Flask documentation, have a look [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/).